# Javascript Form on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

below is my Form

i tried several way to get to try the form.onsubmit to run my post ajax. but i cant get it.

```js
$(document).on("submit", ".btn_create_bin", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("test");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'create_bin' %}" class="btn_create_bin">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div> 
</form>
```

the above javascript is not working, i cant find "test" on my console.

how do I detect when user clicked on Form#btn_create_bin.Submit button?

UPDATED my code to it is less confused, i actually tried some other method and did not remove those testing codes

Comment: The first piece of code looks correct, but there's nothing that I'd call "post ajax" about it.

Comment: @Pointy hi, the first piece of js seems ok to me as well. but i cant get the test out when i check the log

Comment: Code you showed works, see fiddle I made...

Comment: thanks, i realized what is the issue. i am using crispy form and they included </form> which ended my earlier form button.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, did not read django-crispy form clearly.

https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html

simple add below into Form.

```
self.helper.form_tag = False
```

this will not cause crispy to include Form.